# Visual Studio Tools for Unity plugin doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

My system:

1. Windows 10 Pro 1511 10586.36
2. Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
3. Unity 5.2.0f3
4. Visual Studio Tools for Unity 2.1.0.0

My error:

When select File->New->Project->Templates->Game i only can see two templates: Cocos and Unreal Engine.
There is no Unity project template.
However in all articles i was able to find it was said that i only need to install Visual Studio Tools for Unity 
and the Unity itself to achieve integration.
What might be wrong with my installation and setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current workflow with `Unity3D` is to create project from `Unity3D Editor` *(Unity 5.2.0 in your case)* not `VS2015` and then navigate from that editor to VisualStudio / MonoDevelop / VSCode or any other IDE of your choice.
`Unity3D` creates whole solution structure itself and `Visual Studio Tools for Unity` acts only as a bridge between `Unity3D Editor` and `Visual Studio` to allow you to attach to Unity process for debugging purposes, go to file functionality from Unity3D Editor etc.

Comment: Yes and also make sure that you have created at least one CS script otherwise trying opening the solution will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies, your comments pointed to the solution. I actually expected that VS should work with Unity as with any other type of the template project like Win32 or MFC.

I found series of videos where was pointed out how to install VS with Unity.
[Here is link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKHCrRNTf_s&list=PLReL099Y5nRfseAg0k1SJOlpqdcsDs8Em&index=1)

I reinstalled VS and followed video's advices and now demo project is built and work correctly.

Comment: Consider marking helpful answer as resolution then.